# jQuery scrollTop Keeps Triggering Function

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I’m using jQuery to make a header div sticky (with position: fixed) when it’s scrolled past.

Here’s the code I was using, which works great:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y >= 200) {
        $('.top').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.top').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

However I find the UX a little wanting. I started playing around with jQuery UI — which I’m using elsewhere in the site, so it’s already included — and here’s where I’m running into the problem:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y >= 200) {
        $('.top').toggle('fade', 200, function() {
            $('.top').addClass('sticky', function() {
                $('.top').toggle('fade', 200);
            });
        });
    } else {
        $('.top').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

The behaviour I want is that the div fades out, becomes sticky, then fades back in.

It triggers alright, but it just keeps flashing in and out. Toggling the fade over and over.

Could someone give me a tip as to how to achieve my intended behaviour? I just want it to register once it’s scrolled past, whereas it seems like it’s constantly listening to the scroll position.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is the animation has queued and keeps toggling state because it is triggered constantly as you scroll. Eventually, the animation will stop with the duration determined by the distance scrolled.

So you'll need to interrupt the animation.

```
var y = $(this).scrollTop();

if (y >= 200) {        
    $('.top')
        .stop(true, true)
        .fadeOut(200).delay(200)
        .fadeIn(200).addClass('sticky');
} else {
    $('.top').removeClass('sticky');
}
```

jQuery [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jasenhk/FQQTB/)